# update set doesn't work accordingly

Tags: mysql, sql

I am making a timer function that runs in MySQL, and it sets start_time with MySQL CURRENT_TIMESTAMP when they start the timer.

When they stop the timer, I calculate in the SQL the time difference, and add it on to time, and set start_time to 0 again.

```
UPDATE `time`
   SET `time` = time + (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time)),
       `start_time` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' 
 WHERE `id` =  '1'
```

When I stop the timer, instead of using the start_time in the query, it sets it to 0000-00-00 00:00:00 first, so my time is actually `(time + (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('0000-00-00 00:00:00')))`, which is not the correct value.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `time` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `time` double NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `start_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why do you set the start time to zero?  Why do you destroy what might be useful information?

Comment: @tpae; As Jonatahn implies, you should set `start_time` not to zero. Have you tried setting it to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in the update?

Comment: On timer start, it sets start_time to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. on timer stop, it sets start_time to 0. only number I really care about is the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do it in two separate updates?

```
UPDATE `time`
   SET `time` = (time + (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time)))
 WHERE `id` =  '1';

UPDATE `time`
`start_time` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' 
WHERE `id` =  '1'
```

Look at your schema.  The default value is set to that and the update statement is using the current value of it. Are you changing the value of start timer before hand?  Try adding a select before your update to see what the value of start_time is.

I just tried this..

update time
set start_time = '2011-08-28 17:02:47'
where id = 1;

UPDATE `time`
   SET `time` = (time + (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time))), `start_time` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' 
 WHERE `id` =  '1';

and id = 1 got a correct number in time.  Check to make sure start_time and time have good values.

Comment: Same results. It still checks start_time as 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

It's better to change you scheme to:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `time` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `time` double NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT,
  `start_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

);

I mean instaed of '0000...' use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

Another way is to use trigger for this insert action. It will look like:

```
NEW.start_time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: I use start_time = "0000-00-00 00:00:00" to check whether the timer is running or not... is it a bad practice?

Comment: I change start_time once timer starts using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: What's the point of having two fields that are by default set to `CURRENT_TIMETSAMP` (if that is possible)?

Comment: @tpae Check my notes about trigger.

Comment: No, it's impossible to use CURRENT_TIMETSAMP twice. I removed one usage.

Comment: @tpae You can add flag which will indicate starting timer.

Comment: True, but I am assuming the problem is, it's updating start_time BEFORE it runs the UNIX_TIMESTAMP comparison, using my query.

Comment: @tpae I see only one way. It's trigger on before insert action.